# make a file for each block of structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, structure

I have a program for health. In this program, create 4 user accounts except the admin user account. I want to create a text file for each building block that is built in the building section of the user account in this program

```
const int len=6;
struct members {

        string username;
        string password;
        int acsess;

    }mem[len];
```

This is part of my code for memebers and this part is for save memebers

```
{
        ac.mem[0] = {"admin","soran",3};
        ac.mem[1] = { "hamid","hamid",2 };

        ofstream acc1("account");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {

            acc1.write((char*)&ac.mem[i], sizeof(ac.mem[i]));

        }

        acc1.close();

    }
```

for example i run program and log in as admin, When I choose option 4, I can take notes and save it

```
cout << "--------Menu--------" << endl;
        cout << "1.members" << endl;
        cout << "2.claculator" << endl;
        cout << "3.BMI" << endl;
        cout << "4.note" << endl;
        cout << "5.delete history" << endl;
        cout << "6.log out" << endl;
```

Comment: What is your question? You really do not want serialize `std::string` by writing its bytes to a file since you would be serializing just the pointers, not the data directly.

Comment: What I want to do now is add a text file for each block to note each user

Comment: We don't understand what you are asking. Maybe could you give an example or detail your question a bit more. You are free to [edit] your question.

Comment: For example, admin should have a text file, and when I run the program, it will write in the file
I edited it

Comment: Maybe you should add your entire code so we can see the details

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates?

Answer (score 0):

According to your idea, I have compiled a sample for your reference.

Note that this is just a. sample, the code needs to be modified by yourself according to your needs

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct members {
  string username;
  string password;
  int acsess;
} mem[4];
int main() { 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          mem[i].username = "bob";
          mem[i].password = "123456";
          mem[i].acsess = 1;
        }
        string txt = ".txt";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
            {
          ofstream outfile;
          string filename = mem[i].username + txt;
          outfile.open(filename);
          outfile << mem[i].username << endl;
          outfile << mem[i].password << endl;
          outfile << mem[i].acsess << endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```